# How do I implement the add method in this scenario? (Python)

Tags: python, function, methods

I'm learning Python and I cannot find an answer for this:

"Implement the add method. It should add amount to the current field."

```
class Complex:
    def create(self, real_part, imag_part):
        self.r = real_part
        self.i = imag_part

class Calculator:
    current = 0

    def add(self, amount):
        *i need to edit only this line*

    def get_current(self):
        return self.current
```

Comment: This is a question of Pycharm Edu tutorial (introduction to python task 43 of 50)
thanks for share it for us .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def add(self, amount):
    self.current += amount
```

Comment: thank you, that worked and i now understand the content. Thanks!

Comment: @JackHavenar Welcome to Stack Overflow Jack, remember to `Accept` the answer if it answered your question. Click on the grey tick beside the answer.